# Codename one Native implementation with Cocoa Pods Build Error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, codenameone, fbsdkloginkit, fbsdksharekit

I am using the FBSDKLoginKit and the FBSDKCoreKit so I added the build hint ios.pods=FBSDKLoginKit,FBSDKCoreKit however when I sent it for a build I got a build error. The build errors all seemed to revolve around 'Bolts' and 'NSObect' So I added 'Bolts' and 'NSObject' to my ios.pods build hint. That removed all of the previous errors however now I'm getting these errors:

Stack overflow won't let me add the whole log so I put it up on paste bin. Here's the link to the full error log: http://pastebin.com/UdvvjyaV

Comment: Those aren't errors.  They are normal.  If it's failing to build, please post the full output.

Comment: @stevehannah Sorry. Edited in the full output

Comment: I would advise against going in the direction of native facebook integration. It's a hard task that will take weeks to implement in order to workaround an issue that will be resolved in a couple of days...

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Which issue exactly is being resolved and how can you be sure that it will be resolved???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CN1 updated their SDK so there is no need for the cocoa pods